# Full screen mode not hidding the action bar in some devices

Tags: java, android

I'm trying with the following code:

```
findViewById(R.id.button1).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB)
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        getWindow().getDecorView().setSystemUiVisibility(
                View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN
                        | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
    }
});
```

In a Nexus 7 and a HTC One M7 it works as expected, hidding the action bar and the status bar. But in a Samsung Galaxy i9000 and a HTC One X the action bar is still visible. What do I  am doing wrong? Should I call `getActionBar().hide()`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, getActionBar().hide() should work. Add it to your onCreate() function